# C - indexing 2D tiled data with 4D coordinates

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a BC1 texture compressor, which compresses independent 4x4 blocks of texels. I'm taking a 2D image and transforming it into a 2D grid of 4x4 texel blocks, so 2D to 4D. It's actually 5D into 3D, as each texel has 4 components, but that's a simple loop iterating over channels, but those are constant and can be factored out. I know I need 4 nested loops, but the array indexing in 4D broke my brain. This is what I came up with, but it misses ranges of indices. I've clearly done something wrong.

```
#define LIM_X 2
#define LIM_Y 2
#define LIM_I 4
#define LIM_J 4

unsigned int x, y, i, j;
unsigned char src[LIM_Y * LIM_J][LIM_X * LIM_I]; // 8 by 8
unsigned char tmp[LIM_Y][LIM_X][LIM_J][LIM_I];   // 2 by 2 by 4 by 4

for(y = 0; y < LIM_Y; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < LIM_X; x++) {
        for(j = 0; j < LIM_J; j++) {
            for(i = 0; i < LIM_I; i++) {
                tmp[y][x][j][i] = src[y * LIM_J + j][x * LIM_I + i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some debug output for what you're seeing/expect to see? Like you said, this *looks* right.

Comment: Looks correct to me as well. What ranges do you think are missing?